# Deploying to live and available modules

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8 you can export configuration and move that to a production server. In `core.extensions.yml` there is an exported list of the enabled modules. If on development I have devel and other auxiliary modules installed these are added in that file but I do not want that to be part of the production environment.

Is there a switch to do that? How can `master` module from Drupal 7 replicated here?

Comment: Well, obviously you have a flow in your workflow. I think you should look at environment indicator module https://www.drupal.org/project/environment but it's not D8-ready yet.

Comment: In Drupal 7 there is `master` module (https://www.drupal.org/project/master) that takes care of enabling and disabling modules per environment. It actually works really well with `features` and `strongarm`. I am looking to see if I am missing something and something like that is possible with configuration management or a solution that replicates that behaviour.

Comment: What about the config_split module?
Is this something that can cover your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not really a good option for this yet.

It's tricky, because you can't just override the config and have those modules enabled since they also provide their config (which would and install/uninstall processes that can't be skipped. In fact, providing config overrides for core.extension is explicitly prevented.

Maybe someone will come up with a good way to do this, I currently don't really know how that should work.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to disable modules according to the deployment script that one uses. In Acquia there are cloud hooks that can run only on production deployments that could disable some modules.